# converting a tuple consisting of floats and text to one single string

Tags: python, file, text

I'm trying to convert a tuple consisting of 2 floats and 3 parts of text to one string so I can use it in file.write() because it is not accepting tuples.

```
testr = 'you went' ,speed ,'mph and stopped in' ,stop ,'meters'
test = open('testresults.txt' ,'w')
test.write(testr)
test.close()
```

whenever I try to run the program it gives me this

```
    test.write(testr)
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the other answers, this will take your proposed tuple:

```
testr = 'you went' ,speed ,'mph and stopped in' ,stop ,'meters'
test = open('testresults.txt' ,'w')
test.write(" ".join(str(i)for i in testr))
test.close()
```

As only the third line is different from your code, here goes the explanation:

first `str(i)for i in testr`:

the inline `for`-loop is known in python as a [list comprhension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It just iterates over your `testr` tuple, returning the values one by one. `str(i)` is a typecast, it tries to convert `i` into a string. This is necessary as in your tuple some entries are `String`-type and some variables are some type of number, likely `Float` or `Integer`. See [str()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), [float()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) and [int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) for further reading.

Then `" ".join(...)`:

This is a function of the string type that takes a list or tuple of strings and, as the name sugests, joins it together seperated by the substring it acts upon, the part in front of the dot(`" "`). This to me always felt a little weird, or inside-out perhaps, but it is a very usefull function nonetheless!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks It worked! Is it possible you could explain how this works? So I can use this to work in other ways, or other projects I make.

Answer (score 2):

Use `format`:

```
testr = 'you went {} mph and stopped in {} meters'.format(speed, stop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a `String`

```
test.write(str(testr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, python 3.6 makes this very easy and readable for us:

```
testr = f'you went {speed} mph and stopped in {stop} metres'
test = open('testresults.txt' ,'w')
test.write(testr)
test.close()
```

otherwise, the same thing is acheived by using the `string.format(*args)` as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: and how about python2?